# Help finding a database or analysis of plage regions on the Sun

Tags: the-sun, stellar-astrophysics, resource-request, coronal-mass-ejection, sunspots

[Plages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plage_(astronomy)) are phenomena of stellar activity.

> A plage is a bright region in the chromosphere of the Sun, typically found in and around active regions. The term itself is poetically taken from the French word for "beach".
>
> Plage map closely to the bright spots known as faculae in the photosphere below, but the latter have much smaller spatial scales. Accordingly, plage occurs most visibly near active regions. Faculae have a strong influence on the solar constant, **and the more readily detectable plage areas traditionally are used to monitor this influence.** In this context, "active network" consists of plage-like brightenings extending away from active regions as their magnetism appears to diffuse into the quiet Sun, but constrained to follow the network boundaries.

Where can I find open access data of plage regions of the Sun, perhaps with other parameters as well like faculae region, Magnetic field etc?

I've found the following sources that report solar activity and/or contain archives of solar images, but so far no sources where images are processed in order to catalog solar plage areas.

- [Discover the Sun](http://solarcyclescience.com/solarcycle.html)
- [World Data Center for the production, preservation and dissemination of the international sunspot number](https://wwwbis.sidc.be/silso/)
- [Sunspots](https://sohowww.nascom.nasa.gov/sunspots/)
- [National Solar Observatory Global Oscillation Network Group](https://gong.nso.edu/)
- [Solar Ham](https://www.solarham.net/)

---

[image]

Cropped from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Calcium_K_Mosaic_2015_04_18_(16569533153).jpg)

> 1000/102mm refractor Lunt B1200 CaK module Baader K line filter Skyris 274m CCD camera Hinode guider, Ioptron ZEQ25GT mount 18 April 2015, 20:34 [original](https://www.flickr.com/photos/16271433@N02/16569533153/)

Comment: There is quite a lot of data on these site:
https://gong.nso.edu/
https://www.solarham.net/ I don't know if this is at the level of detail you want, but if not, maybe the links therein help.

Comment: Some sources I have found so far! [Discover the Sun](http://solarcyclescience.com/solarcycle.html) [World Data Center for the production, preservation and dissemination of the international sunspot number](https://wwwbis.sidc.be/silso/) [Sunspots](https://sohowww.nascom.nasa.gov/sunspots/) [National Solar Observatory Global Oscillation Network Group](https://gong.nso.edu/) [Solar Ham](https://www.solarham.net/)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is exactly the sort of question Google is perfect for. When I entered those search terms I got most of the sites you put in your answer in the first two pages of results. The question doesn't need Stack Exchange.

Comment: I myself searched and answered my question. Why to close if someone can take benefit from it?

Comment: You should put your answer as a written answer.

Comment: @JustinTackett it seems the OP did just that but a list of links is not an answer in Stack Exchange so it was then deleted. I've moved them up into the question.

Comment: @Autodidact I've moved your links into your question, so far I can't find a list of plages in any of those links so I think there is still room for a more complete answer. It seems that *somebody, somewhere* must be doing a plage analysis on images, so I've added a bounty to see if we can find it.